# Presto server fails to start with hive catalog

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, presto

We installed a presto server on a VM, configured a connection to HDP cluster using hive.properties

```
connector.name=hive-hadoop2
hive.config.resources=/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml,/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml 
hive.security=read-olny 
hive.metastore.uri=thrift://XXX:9083 
hive.metastore.authentication.type=KERBEROS 
hive.metastore.username=presto 
hive.metastore.client.keytab=/etc/security/keytabs/presto.keytab 
hive.metastore.client.principal=presto@EXAMPLE.COM 
hive.metastore.service.principal=hive/_HOST@EXAMPLE.COM 
hive.hdfs.authentication.type=KERBEROS hive.hdfs.presto.principal=presto@EXAMPLE.COM 
hive.hdfs.presto.keytab=/etc/security/keytabs/presto.keytab
```

The server is failing to start with errors as below:

```
2020-01-29T14:06:55.627+0200    ERROR   main    com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer Guice configuration errors:

1) Explicit bindings are required and com.facebook.presto.spi.connector.ConnectorAccessControl is not explicitly bound.
  while locating com.facebook.presto.spi.connector.ConnectorAccessControl

1 error
com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) Explicit bindings are required and com.facebook.presto.spi.connector.ConnectorAccessControl is not explicitly bound.
  while locating com.facebook.presto.spi.connector.ConnectorAccessControl

1 error
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1075)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1034)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1086)
        at com.facebook.presto.hive.HiveConnectorFactory.create(HiveConnectorFactory.java:144)
        at com.facebook.presto.connector.ConnectorManager.createConnector(ConnectorManager.java:364)
        at com.facebook.presto.connector.ConnectorManager.addCatalogConnector(ConnectorManager.java:222)
        at com.facebook.presto.connector.ConnectorManager.createConnection(ConnectorManager.java:214)
        at com.facebook.presto.connector.ConnectorManager.createConnection(ConnectorManager.java:200)
        at com.facebook.presto.metadata.StaticCatalogStore.loadCatalog(StaticCatalogStore.java:96)
        at com.facebook.presto.metadata.StaticCatalogStore.loadCatalogs(StaticCatalogStore.java:74)
        at com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer.run(PrestoServer.java:132)
        at com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer.main(PrestoServer.java:74)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

There is a typo:

```
hive.security=read-olny
```

should be

```
hive.security=read-only
```

Using this occasion, I suggest that you upgrade to a newer version. Presto 329 is the latest -- https://trino.io/download.html